# Minimum number of data sets for 'good enough' curve?

Tags: statistics

Sorry if I don't articulate my question very well, statistics isn't my strength.

Trying to put it simply, I run a single (non-deterministic) simulation which gives me a simple x vs y relationship. I then run multiple simulations (say N) and average over them to give a better estimate of y. My problem is how long it takes to get N sets of data, so I want to minimise the number I need whilst maintaining a good estimate of y, so that future data gathering is quicker.

My approach so far has been to calculate the residual sum of squares (RSS) for y as measured by n (random) sets of data (n < N) compared to y as measured by the total N sets (as I have no other estimate of y). I do this for increasing n (say n = 10, 20, 30, etc.) and plot n against RSS(n). I get a curve that I somewhat expected: exponential decay in RSS(n), which is almost linear on a semilogy plot.

I guess my questions are:

1. Does this method make sense? I'm not sure about using the RSS with my own data (using N data sets) as a reference.
2. A big problem I have is if I don't choose the n sets at random, but instead choose the first n sets I gathered (i.e. use sets 1:20 for n=20, then sets 1:40 for n=40, etc). The curve changes quite drastically, as instead of continually decreasing, it seems to 'level out' in the middle of my range of n. I can't explain this at all.

Thanks for any help!

[Plot with n random data sets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83sKm.png)

[Plot with the first n data sets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8wLa.png)

Edit: I've added the two curves I get, the first using n random sets, and the second using the first n sets. I am struggling to understand the flatter region of the second plot, between n ~ 60 and n ~ 150.

Comment: Are you able to provide (perhaps blinded) sample data and/or images showing the behaviours you are seeing and highlighting what you do not like?

Comment: Thanks. I've added the plots now.